# Facebook Graph Api - Posting to page without logging

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I'm trying to create a script that post status updates on facebook pages without logging-in the user. I've got access_token for my application and for the pages as the user granted the application once; but I always get the error

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

despite I've granted **manage_pages** and **publish_stream** permission.
Also if I use the access_token for the page I get the error

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.
```

Here is the code I use.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'XXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
));

$post = array(
    'message'   => 'Message to user'/*,
     access_token = "XXXXXXXX"*/
);
$feed = '/[PAGE_ID]/feed';

$post_id = $facebook->api($feed, "post", $post);
```

Thanks.

**Edit :**

I finally managed to post status updates on a user's page while this user was disconnected, I had to generate the access_token through the server-side auth method.

Comment: Make sure you have 2 tokens, User Auth token and Page Auth token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a small code smaple on how to do a FB post to a page:

yOU NEED:

- Your_authToken_for_User
- List item

saved_fb_Page_Token

```
 $facebook = $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $fbAppId,
                'secret' => $fbAppSecret,
                'cookie' => true,
            ));
    $facebook->setAccessToken("Your_authToken_for_User");

   //Now your FB instance is authenticated.

    $pages= $facebook->api('/me/accounts'); //use the current authenticated FB instance to grab Pages. If you already know your page ID , skip this.

   //Assuming you have a pageid in $page_id,(the $page_id can be grabbed from the $pages array).

    $attachment = array(
                'access_token' => $saved_fb_Page_Token,
                'message' => "foo",
                'name' => "Bar",
                'link' => "http://foo.bar",
                'description' => "barfoo",
                'picture' => "an image url here",
            );

     $facebook->api('/' . $page_id . '/feed', 'POST', $attachment);//post to fb page
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I managed to post to the page with it. But as soon as the user log out I'm facing the "session is invalid" error. Also I believe the user auth token is valid for 60 days max. Is there any way to bypass the user auth process since the app has already been validated by the account ? Or any way to get a permanent user auth token ?

Comment: You need to read this : https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/